# Python 2.7 Pip module not installing or setting paths via cmd?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I've been having some really odd issues with trying to install and use the Python "Pip" module. Firstly, I've installed the pip module by downloading the getpip.py file and running it which has replaced my pre existing pip which seemed to work fine. However whenever I try to use pip it always comes up with "pip is not recognized as an internal or external command" etc. I've set the path for python by using setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python27\python" and then using C:\Python27\Scripts\pip the second time to try and set the path for pip. But one of these seem to work. I can't use pip in cmd neither can I now use python.

Does anyone know how to make this work? I'm trying to run this command "pip install -r requirements.txt " even in the right folder but pip is not recognized. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Use the built-in `set` command, not `setx.exe`. Using `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python27\python"` sets the expanded and concatenated system + user value permanently as your per-user `PATH` value, i.e. it makes a giant mess. `setx` also has no effect on the current command prompt, unlike `set`. Also, `setx.exe` is a bad tool for modifying the value of `PATH`. It doesn't allow appending to the user or system value, so you'd have to hack something out using `reg.exe`. It's better to just use the control panel app for this.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong path, Pip should reside in the `Scripts`  sub directory, set PATH to `C:\Python27\Scripts` then you should restart cmd.